# Specify Image Width and Height being called by PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to figure out where to specify the image size of the `facebook.png`, which is 24x24.

Below is the code, but I am not sure how to specify the size. I know how to do this in HTML, but not in PHP.

```
<?php if ( get_option('solostream_facebook_url') ) { ?>
    <a title="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" rel="external" href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_url')); ?>"><img class="facebook-sub" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" align="top" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: <img width="24" height="24" class="facebook-sub" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" align="top" />

Comment: Please explain your question clearly, what do you want actually?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `height` and `width` attributes to `<img>`. Check below code.

```html
<?php if ( get_option( 'solostream_facebook_url') ) { ?>
<a title="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" rel="external" href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_url')); ?>"><img class="facebook-sub" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" align="top" height="24" width="24"/></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tryying to get PHP to retrieve the width / height?

If so, the `getimagesize()` function will do this:

```
<?php if ( get_option('solostream_facebook_url') ) { ?>
    list($width, $height, $type, $dims) = getimagesize("bloginfo('template_directory')/images/facebook.png");
    <a title="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" rel="external" href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_url')); ?>"><img $dims class="facebook-sub" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('solostream_facebook_link_text')); ?>" align="top" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```